# Im trying to calculate the number off days between 2 date objects

Tags: java

```
public static int countWeeks() {
    // setting dates
    Calendar calStart = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
    calStart.set(2014, 8, 30);
    Date dateStart = calStart.getTime();

    Date dateEnd = new Date();

    // count days and weeks
    int diffInDays = Days.daysBetween(new DateTime(dateStart), new DateTime(dateEnd)).getDays(); //         int weekNumber = (int) diffInDays / 7;

    return weekNumber;

}
```

I'm trying to calculate the number of days and weeks between today and last week but I always get -3 as weekNumber. I have no idea what i'm doing wrong.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is this `Days` class? If it is JodaTime, you should explain it since it is not part of Java API

Comment: `int weekNumber` is commented out? So where is `weekNumber` declared?

Comment: Also, remember that months in Calendar are 0-based, so you are actually setting the start at setember, 30th. Better use `Calendar.AUGUST` for that.

Comment: Get the milliseconds, substract end from start. Divide by 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24. Have you day difference.

Answer (score 1):

First, I will assume that

```
int weekNumber = (int) diffInDays / 7;
```

is not commented since otherwise you would get a compilation error.

Now, as explained in my comment, by doing

```
calStart.set(2014, 8, 30);
```

You are setting the date at the end of setember, not of august. So, it is 3 weeks ahead of now, so you get a `-3`. Use the `Calendar`  constants.

```
calStart.set(2014, Calendar.AUGUST, 30);
```

Comment: the weekNumber was indeed not suposed to be commented xd
It works perfect now thanks :p

Answer (score 0):

You are getting -3 as the weeknumber since you have commented that out so it showing some random value. Also note that 8 shows the September month not Aug since months are 0 based.

So if you are aiming at August month then you may try this:

```
calStart.set(2014, 7, 30);
                   ^^-- This represents August month
```

Comment: If the code was commented he would get a compilation error...

Comment: @SJuan76:- Yes that makes sense. Then probably the issue is with the month as the gettime() will get the present date and the 8 is the September month as against the Aug which I guess OP is thinking :)

Answer (score 0):

You set the startdate to Sep. 30th because te month is zero bases!

See the documentation from java.util.Calendar:

> public final void set(int year,
>          int month,
>          int date) Sets the values for the calendar fields YEAR, MONTH, and DAY_OF_MONTH. Previous values of other calendar fields are
>   retained. If this is not desired, call clear() first. Parameters: year
>   - the value used to set the YEAR calendar field. month - the value used to set the MONTH calendar field. Month value is 0-based. e.g., 0
>   for January. date - the value used to set the DAY_OF_MONTH calendar
>   field. See Also:

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Java 8 you can use the Java time API:

```
LocalDate start = LocalDate.of(2014, 8, 30);
LocalDate end = LocalDate.now();
long days = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(start, end);
return (int) days / 7;
```